# conditional manipulating of reoccuring variables

Tags: r

I have the following, simplified data frame.

```
obj <- data.frame (id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),
Date = c("1990-01", "1990-02", "1990-03", "1990-04", "1990-01", "1990-02", "1990-03", "1990-04", "1991-01", "1991-02", "1991-03", "1991-04", "1991-01", "1991-02", "1991-03", "1991-04"),
                   degree = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1)
)
```

Note that my real ID's are named something like `2.01811e+13`

What I would like to do is the following:

- I would like to create a new column which should be 1 for a date
  where `degree` turns to 2 and the previous observation is 1 for the same ID.
- For every `degree` = 1 the new column should be zero.
- For any `degree` = 0 the new column should take NA.
- For any other `degree` = 2 (so if the previous degree of the same id observation was not 1) the new column should be NA as well.

Note that consecutive id observations might overlap across years in the real sample, e.g. an ID ranging from 1990-11, 1990-12, 1991-01, 1991-02.

it should look like this,

```
id date    new_col 
1   1990-01   0
1   1990-02   0 
1   1990-03   0
1   1990-04   1
2   1990-01   0
2   1990-02   0
2   1990-03   NA
2   1990-04   NA
1   1991-01   0
1   1991-02   1
1   1991-03   NA
1   1991-04   NA
2   1991-01   0
2   1991-02   0
2   1991-03   1
2   1991-04   0
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add the column `degree` to your output data for more clarity.

Comment: @c0bra thanks for your response! I've added the column degree into my answer as well as I changed my reproducible example slightly so that its is clear that the conditions dependt on variable ID. Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to edit my posts yet. 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tidyverse option using `case_when()`.

```
library(dplyr)

obj %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(new_col = case_when(degree == 2 & lag(degree) == 1 ~ 1,
                             degree == 1 ~ 0,
                             T ~ NA_real_))

# # A tibble: 16 x 4
# # Groups:   id [2]
#       id Date    degree new_col
#    <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1      1 1990-01      1       0
# 2      1 1990-02      1       0
# 3      1 1990-03      1       0
# 4      1 1990-04      2       1
# 5      2 1990-01      1       0
# 6      2 1990-02      1       0
# 7      2 1990-03      0      NA
# 8      2 1990-04      1       0
# 9      1 1991-01      2      NA
# 10     1 1991-02      2      NA
# 11     1 1991-03      2      NA
# 12     1 1991-04      2      NA
# 13     2 1991-01      1       0
# 14     2 1991-02      1       0
# 15     2 1991-03      2       1
# 16     2 1991-04      2      NA
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help! Unfortunately, your code assigns 1 to new_ccol in any case when degree is 2 and the degree variable is 1 and assigns these values, therefore, independent of the id variable. As my real sample is large and the probability that for the last observation of a given id the degree is 1 and the following observation, a first observation of another id, the variable degree takes the value 2, new_col would turn to 1. This should be not the case, as new_col should be just 1 if degree is 2 and the previous degree is 0 FOR THE SAME ID.

Comment: @freddywit: You are very welcome. I have edited my post to supply the output you are after.

Answer (score 0):

This is updated reprex where the condition : if degree = 2 and previous degree = 1 then new_col = 1 does hold just if it is the same ID.

```
 obj <- data.frame (id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),
    Date = c("1990-01", "1990-02", "1990-03", "1990-04", "1990-01", "1990-02", "1990-03", "1990-04", "1991-01", "1991-02", "1991-03", "1991-04", "1991-01", "1991-02", "1991-03", "1991-04"),
                       degree = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2)
    )
```

with the desired output

```
   id date    degree new_col 
    1   1990-01   1     0
    1   1990-02   1     0 
    1   1990-03   1     0
    1   1990-04   2     1
    2   1990-01   1     0
    2   1990-02   1     0
    2   1990-03   0     NA
    2   1990-04   1     0
    1   1991-01   2     NA
    1   1991-02   2     NA
    1   1991-03   2     NA
    1   1991-04   2     NA
    2   1991-01   1     0
    2   1991-02   1     0
    2   1991-03   2     1
    2   1991-04   2     NA
```

Best regards,

Freddy